# How to find Gameobjects by name or tag and add them to a array one by one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am trying to find Gameobjects(instantiated)from the hierarchy by tag.I want to add the Gameobjects one by one to an array.

```
GameObject []insta1;

 for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
        {
            insta1= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Vid2");


        }
```

The **above code** is working but I want something like given below like save them in position and later take them **one by one** and perform separate actions.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
        {
            insta1[i]= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Vid2");


        }
```

Comment: `FindGameObjectsWithTag` already returns an array, whats wrong with using it?

Answer (score 2):

FindGameObjectsWithTag already returns an GameObject[] as seen in: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html

So you can simply do:

```
GameObject[] foundObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Vid2");
```

and then loop over them with:

```
foreach (GameObject foundObject in foundObjects) {
  //Do Whatever you want with the gameObject
}
```

or just access them with:

```
foundObjects[index]
```

Answer (score 2):

Performance wise, you might want to implement it like this instead.

**FindGameObjectsWithTag** is slow depends on your scene since it needs to go through the gameObjects that are present in the scene and check their tag.

For this, we'll be using a **Singleton Pattern** to make sure that we'll only have 1 instance of "MyClass" gameObject.

For more information about the singleton pattern, you might want to read this as well:
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

This one is much easier to understand: 
https://codeburst.io/singleton-design-pattern-implementation-in-c-62a8daf3d115

**Example:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This is basic a singleton implementation
    static MyClass sharedInstance = null;
    public static MyClass GetInstance()
    {
        if(sharedInstance == null)
        {
            // Create a "MyClassSingleton" gameObject if for the first time
            GameObject g = new GameObject("MyClassSingleton");
            // Attach "MyClass" component and set our instance
            sharedInstance = g.AddComponent<MyClass>();
        }
        return sharedInstance;
    }

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject myGameObjectPrefab;

    List<GameObject> myGameObjectList;

    void Awake()
    {
        // Intialize our list
        myGameObjectList = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    public void SpawnGameObject(Vector3 position)
    { 
        // Instantiate the gameObject
        GameObject g = GameObject.Instantiate(myGameObjectPrefab);
        // Set the position of the gameObject
        g.transform.position = position;
        // Add the instantiated gameObject to our list
        myGameObjectList.Add(g);
    }

    public List<GameObject> GetGameObjectList()
    {
        return myGameObjectList;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // For spawning the game objects
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            SpawnGameObject(Vector3.zero);
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            List<GameObject> list = GetGameObjectList();
            if(list != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("COUNT: " + list.Count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to spawn (from other class):

```
MyClass.GetInstance().SpawnGameObject(Vector3.zero);
```

How to get all of the gameObjects (from other class):

```
List<GameObject> gameObjectList = MyClass.GetInstance().GetGameObjectList();
```

Note: You can invoke those two methods from a different class (just make sure that their access modifier is set to "public").